# Add specific page of Visio diagram into Word document

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-visio, microsoft-word-2013

I've got a Visio 2010 document that has multiple pages, with one workflow on each page. I'm trying to insert each of the workflows into a word 2013 document. I'm trying to do it as a direct link so I only need to update the Visio diagram to update the word doc as well.

However, whenever I try to link to the Visio document, it's only inserting the first page, and I cant' find any option to add any of the other pages.

Anyone know how I can insert any of the other pages in the Visio diagram into my Word doc?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suspect that you are inserting the link by going to Word's Insert tab, Text group, then clicking the Object dropdown and selecting Object. If you go that route, Word does not offer any of the internal objects in the Visio file.

If so, you may find it easier to start with the Visio file open in Visio (one reason is that you don't have to remember the names of all the pages/objects), then

- Select the tab of the page that you want to link to
- Click Copy
- In Word's Home tab, Click the arrow at the bottom of the Paste button
- Click Paste Special...
- Click the Paste Link radio button
- Click the format you want (e.g. Microsoft Visio Drawing object)
- Click OK

Incidentally,

(a) you can link to things other than complete pages such as individual shapes and grouped shapes using this technique (or the one described by Johnny Estilles, as long as you know the correct name to use for the shape).

(b) I think in Visio you will always get the first page in the closed file on disk when you insert the link using the Insert->Object route, even when Visio is open. If you resequence the page tabs in Visio, and update the link, nothing happens until you save and close. I mention this because not all programs behave the same way. e.g. when you do the same thing with an Excel workbook, if the workbook is open when you perform the insertion or update the link, what you get is the open Worksheet. If the workbook is closed, you get the first worksheet.

Comment: @user181946, your suggestion is infinitely easier than the officially recommend solution that uses the Insert Object "feature."

Answer (score 7):

Let assume you have a Visio diagram with 2 pages named `Page-1` and `Page-2`.

Once you've linked the Visio diagram you can display `Page-2` by doing this:

- Right click on the Visio object, select `Linked Visio Object` -> `Links`
- On the `Links` popup, click the `Change Source` button
- On the `Change Source` popup, click the `Item Buttom`
- On the `Item:` prompt enter `Drawing\~` followed by the name of the page you want to display (e.g. `Drawing\~Page-2`) and click `OK`
- Back on the `Change Source` popup, re-select the file for the Visio Diagram and click `Open`
- Back on the `Links` popup click `OK`

And ... *voilà* ... Page-2 of your diagram is displayed.

Comment: Thanks. Definitely works. I tried both this and bibadia's method below. Up voted yours and marked his as the answer just because his is more complete.

Comment: I agree. @bibadia's answer is definitely more complete! Up voting as well. :-)